# Segmentation in the declaration of a string

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when running my program, 
the program is compiled with g++ using the -g tag.
I then used gdb to debug the program:

source code extract (clinicFunctions.cpp):

```
void loadTreatments(string &file, string treatments[20], int &treatmentsCount){

cout << "---LOADING TREATMENTS---" << endl;

ifstream reader(file.c_str());
int lineCounter = 1;



if(!reader){
    cerr << "**Error opening file: " << file << "**" << endl;
}

while (reader){
    string line;  //LINE 299, ERROR OCCURS HERE
    int stringLength;
    size_t location;
    char extraction[20];
    size_t length;

    string treatment;

    getline(reader, line);
    stringLength = line.length();
    location = line.find(".");
```

gdb result:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x77923654 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x77923654 in ?? ()
#1  0x775e70b5 in msvcrt!free () from C:\windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
#2  0x00990000 in ?? ()
#3  0x6fe5a624 in ?? () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#4  0x6fec971f in ?? () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#5  0x6fed6353 in ?? () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#6  0x6fed63a1 in ?? () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#7  0x6feda29b in ?? () from C:\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
#8  0x00402fb1 in _fu22___ZSt4cerr () at clinicFunctions.cpp:299
#9  0x00401643 in main (argc=5, argv=0x990ea0) at clinic.cpp:48
```

This error happens in the third loop of `while (reader)`

Comment: For starters, did you ever actually check to make sure `getline` and `find` succeeded before you use the results? C-style arrays are always a good place to start when debugging segfaults. What're you using `extraction` for?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line in particular. You're corrupting memory somewhere else. Please spend some time to narrow down the problem and create a [mcve] that is as small as possible and still segfaults.

Comment: `length = line.copy(extraction, location, 0); extraction[length] = '\0';` it is used to get the data of the line

Comment: Running through valgrind, or also compiling with `-fsanitize=address` can help find the location where you're causing the problem.